# Three JS - How to cut a 3D object with Y plane?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, mesh

Is it possible, with Three JS, to cut a mesh or an object with a plane (mostly with Y axis) that we can move ?
I want the same functionality that display in this picture :

[image: Y plane with 3D object]

The goal is to keep the mesh intact to allow for the user moving the plane and see the mesh in function of the Y plane.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "cut" means? Should we assume you want to add new vertices at the planar intersection to keep the mesh intact? Do you want a solid face, or multiple faces only on solid parts? E.g. In your image the center seems to be hollow, are you trying to preserve that along the cutting edge?

Comment: If you don't care about having a valid mesh, and just want to render something that looks "cut", you can achieve that in a shader by discarding the fragments on the opposite side of the plane.

Comment: See any of the three.js clipping examples. For example: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_clipping.html

Comment: Here's a video of the effect for anyone who can't load WebGL: https://vimeo.com/144777216

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on WestLangley's comment, the following code from the [sample link](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_clipping.html) he posted seems to be the relevant bit for what you're trying to achieve:

```
// ***** Clipping planes: *****
var localPlane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0), 0.8);

// Geometry
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x80ee10,
    shininess: 100,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,

    // ***** Clipping setup (material): *****
    clippingPlanes: [ localPlane ],
    clipShadows: true
});

var geometry = new THREE.TorusKnotBufferGeometry(0.4, 0.08, 95, 20);

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.castShadow = true;
scene.add(mesh);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for have been so fast. I didn't see this example (there are a lot!). I will look at this and see if it works for my 3D object.

Comment: This really helped! One thing I'd add is that in order for this to work, it's necessary to set the renderer's `localClippingEnabled` property to `true`.

Example:

`const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: myExampleCanvas }); renderer.localClippingEnabled = true;`

Relevant docs:
https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=material#api/en/materials/Material.clippingPlanes

Comment: @yaphi1 That's great context, thanks for the addendum!